# How do I use node-inspector to debug a KrakenJs app?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector, kraken.js

I'm testing out the KrakenJs framework that builds on ExpressJs. If I were using ExpressJs I could just start debugging by running these commands in two separate shells:

```
node --debug myApp.js
node-inspector
```

Then if I can debug using something like the chrome-devtools console if I navigate to the URL `http://localhost:8000/debug?port=5858`

But KrakenJs tells me this:

> The URL /debug?port=5858 did not resolve to a route.

Which makes sense because KrakenJs doesn't have a route defined. Is there a way to tell KrakenJs to honor a debug request? Perhaps by forwarding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I need to read my console output from node-inspector more carefully. I was hitting my app by going to the URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/debug?port=5858
```

My console output from node-inspector was telling me to go through 127.0.0.1. I had initially ignored that, forgetting that node really does look at the URL and so node-inspector must as well. I was able to get to the debug console on chrome by going to this URL instead:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/debug?port=5858
```